# Dreamweaver upload issue

Tags: dreamweaver

I have created a site using Dreamweaver CS6.  I have uploaded it, through Dreamweaver, to my ftp space.  Everything is displaying as it should on the uploaded site apart from the header.  It has worked consistantly during the creation of the site, and I have previewed the file on the remote server and it is definitely on there.  It has been pointed out that this question is not quite clear - the problem I am having is that the header does not display as it should.

Can anyone suggest why this might be happening?  Its a simple jpeg image, of which I have several on the site, all of which are working.

Cheers for any assistance

Comment: You didn't actually state the problem you are having.  Please re-word.

Comment: As I said, everything is displaying as it should apart from the header.  Therefore, the problem I am having is that the header is not displaying as it should.

Comment: Can we see sample code that includes the header SRC call, or background CSS?   Is the image itself also uploaded to the server in the correct pathed location?  Can you open the header image alone in the browser via site.com/<imgpath>/image.jpg style url?

Comment: Here is the relevant CSS.  I can open the jpeg itself in the manner you describe.

`#header 
{
 background-image: url("images/Capture3.jpg");
 width: 302px;
 height: 83px;
 margin-bottom: 22px;
}
`

Comment: hmm.  I used the ` ` convention to post code and and still posted like this for some reason...

Comment: yeah, code doesn't work in the comments block...   edit the orig. post  .   The css looks correct for a header div to have a background.    Test that yourdomain.com/images/Capture3.jpg exists.  If you are on a Linux host, remember that file names and paths ARE case sensitive.

Comment: Ahh, ok.  Well, the file does exist and its in the right folder.  Im on windows rather than linux, but Ive checked the case as well and its all ok.  Could it be something to do with the structure of the divs?  The header itself is inside a container div - its the only thing left that I can think of that could be causing the issue.

Comment: OK.  I have finally worked out the problem!  There was one capitalisation that I had missed.  How can I mark this as solved?

Comment: Hi, I'll post an answer comment, and then you can accept it.   Thanks and gald you got it figured out with my advice :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After discussing with Peter, the problem lay with the path being case-sensitive.

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved this question - it was due to a capitalisation issue that I had missed (I had mistakenly spelled a filename in CSS with a capital letter).  My thanks to briansol for his help.